# How to save Custom Object with Calendar fields in SQLLite database in Android?

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization, gson

Below is a custom class that I have that I want to store in `SQLlite` Database. I want to store and then retrieve the entire `Calendar` fields `startTime` and `endTime` so that I can use all the fields of `Calendar` type later.

I know SQLLite stores `String` and `Int` only. Is there a way to store a custom class with SQLLite?

I know that the `Gson` library can help but is my code below correct?

```
public class Model_BlockTimes {

Calendar startTime;
Calendar endTime;


public Model_BlockTimes() {
}

public Model_BlockTimes(Calendar startTime, Calendar endTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

public Calendar getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(Calendar startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public Calendar getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}

public void setEndTime(Calendar endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}
}
```

My test code to convert to and from Gson, not working.

**Can I store the response from the function `convertToJson(...)` be stored and retrieved from the sqllite like this?:

```
public String convertToJson(Model_BlockTimes times) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String resp = gson.toJson(times);

    return resp;
}
```

How to convert back from Json to `Model_BlockTimes` back?

Comment: convert date in string format and store in database

Comment: I know but is there a way to store custom objects with fields also as custom objects in sqllite db? I am trying to use this for a lot of classes, otherwise will have write to and from string converters for each member field of the different classes.

Comment: Its sort of the nature of the beast when dealing with persistence. If you're saving a ton of information it may be best to approach it from more of a normalization perspective and look at what information can be generated at runtime rather than saving all of it individually. 

Also, parsing to json then converting back to an object is a valid approach for complex objects, but you can't avoid writing a "how to save this" for objects in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize one object use

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Model_BlockTimes item = gson.fromJson(json, Model_BlockTimes.class);
```

Where json is serialized json string.

BTW, sqlite has 5 [types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and with BLOB you may use protobuf to save some space.